# Alert pop up when a NewForm is loaded

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like an alert pop-up to be loaded when a user clicks New Item in a sharepoint list.
I want the alert popup to say something like:
“You are about to create a New List Item, please verify that you have completed a search of the library before submitting”
Ok/Cancel

If the user clicks Ok, the NewForm opens, if the user clicks Cancel, the user returns to the ViewList.

The searches I have done so far only show me how to launch a popup when the user presses Save on a NewForm.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show some code for what you have done so far. Maybe we can work it from there...

Comment: An alternative approach would be to edit the New Item form and add the message there, not as a pop-up, but it would nevertheless display the message to users.

Comment: I put a CEWP in the NewForm.aspx with a link to a .js file stored in my site assets: the .js says <script type=“text/javascript”> function LiveAlert(){alert(‘my text....’);return true;} </script>

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you have already taken of putting the script that shows your alert pop-up on the New form itself is a good approach.  But what you want is not an `alert`, but a [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) pop-up.  This will give you the OK/Cancel buttons, and once the user clicks one of the buttons, you can check what they clicked, and if they clicked "Cancel", you can then invoke the New form's regular "Cancel" button click from your script.

You tagged your question [sharepoint-online](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-online), so I'm not quite sure what the correct selectors are that you should use to find the cancel button in SP Online, but here is an example for SP 2013:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showConfirm() {

    var cancelButton = document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="Cancel"]');

    var shouldCreateNew = confirm('You are about to create a New List Item, please verify that you have completed a search of the library before submitting.');

    // the confirm pop-up will return true if the user clicks OK, and false if the user clicks Cancel

    if (!shouldCreateNew) {
        cancelButton.click();
    }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('showConfirm');

</script>
```

Again, for SP Online you may have to adjust what's in the `document.querySelector()` in order to grab the Cancel button.

Comment: Thanks, the confirm form is not popping up when I click the New Item. I tried it as CEWP and Scripteditor.  Could it be clashing with a CEWP that is already associated with the NewForm?

Comment: Maybe?  Hard to tell... if you open the dev tools for your browser, do you see any errors in the console?  Also, if you are on SP Online, are you on classic or modern experience?